# Using linear mixed models to evaluate simulation experiment results

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, simulation

I have a simulation experiment to test different statistical models. My simulations have three factors that I have varied (A and B) and from these simulations, I've sampled some data, calibrated models and tested their predictive accuracy.

These simulations are agent based models, where A consists of 8 parameter sets for the ABM, B is 20 spatial grids that the ABM is simulated in. So the factors are A (n=8) and B (n=20). But what I am interested in are how the attributes of the simulated landscapes and the simulation outputs have on prediction accuracy of the statistical models.

Initially, I thought a linear mixed model would work as exploratory analysis shows that the relationships between the measured attributes and measures of accuracy were linear and clearly clustered when grouped by factors A and B. The model I was looking to use is :

```
auc ~ attribute_1+attribute_2...+attribute_5 + (1|A) + (1|B)
```

However, I have concerns this may not be the way to go. For example, attributes of factor B (landscapes) vary around 20 unique values, while simulation attributes vary around 1,600 unique values (8 ABM parameters x 20 landscapes x 10 replicates).

My concerns are that:

1. Attributes just describing factor B have random intercepts, but each random intercept will pass through one point of data of the independent variable and have high variance (see image below as example). **Am I better off dropping this variable and analysing any relationships between it and model accuracy via any residual trends?**

[image]

2. The fixed effects are essentially a function of the two random effects. Exploratory analysis shows that there are linear relationships between model accuracy and the fixed effects and that the intercepts do vary depending on the factors, so the model makes sense in that regard. **But does this functional dependence between random and fixed effects cause issues in terms of biasing model results, violating model assumptions?**

Note: QQ plots look approximately normal, histograms of residuals also confirm this. Plots of residuals vs fitted show do show some anomalies

[image]